# Flatten terraform (HCL) object into a list

Tags: list, dictionary, terraform, flatten, hcl

I have a list of object as such

```
secret_list = [
 { 
   secret1 = {}
   secret2 = {}
 },
 {
   secret3 = {}
 }
]
```

and i want to flatten this out so they become a list or map of 3 objects like:

```
secret_list = [
 { 
   secret1 = {}
 },
 {
   secret2 = {}
 },
 {
   secret3 = {}
 }
]
```

Comment: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten please check this

Answer (score 0):

If all the keys across all the maps are unique you can use the solution in `secret_list2`. However if you have duplicate keys between maps then use the solution in `secret_list3`

```
locals {
  secret_list = [
    {
      secret1 = {}
      secret2 = {}
    },
    {
      secret3 = {}
    }
  ]
  secret_list2 = [for k, v in merge(local.secret_list...): {(k): v}]
  secret_list3 = flatten([for secret in local.secret_list: [for k, v in secret: {(k): v}]])
}

output "foo" {
  value = local.secret_list2
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Outputs:

foo = [
  {
    "secret1" = {}
  },
  {
    "secret2" = {}
  },
  {
    "secret3" = {}
  },
]
```